How to export the given data to be imported by python?
Consider the following data:
data = {{"string1", {112, 123, -999, 12}, 
    Table[{x, 13*x^2}, {x, 0., 1., 0.12}], 
    "cos(x)+sin(y)"}, {"string2", {113, 113, -999, -999}, 
    Table[{x, 7*Sqrt[x]}, {x, 0., 1., 0.12}], "cos(x)+cos(y)"}};

Which format should I use for its exporting to be properly imported in python?
I.e., after importing, the first element of the row must be a string, the second element - a table, and the third element as an another string (that may be then directly converted into an expression).
Ideally, it would be exporting in .mx format and then interpreting inside the python code.

This question is similar to: Prepare Mathematica output to be parsed in Python. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem. Also, there are several other questions about data transfer between Wolfram Kernel and python, please search the site.

@Domen : I am more interested in exporting/importing format rather than converting the Mathematica-type input inside python.

What do you mean by exporting/importing? To a file? How do you want this data to be represented in python? With lists? With numpy.array? How do you want to treat "cos(x)+cos(y)" in python? As a string? Your question is unclear.

@Domen : I have added a clarification.

Have you tried Export["test.json", data, "JSON"] in MMA?   An example of importing the json into python would be the CLI command python -c 'import json; f = open("test.json"); print(json.load(f)); f.close()'

@LouisB : thanks! It may work.
